# Method MainView called from AppDelegate runs but there are no changes to the interface

Tags: iphone, interface, nib

I have this in my myApp_AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

MainViewController *mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];

    [mainVC someMethod];

    return YES;     }
```

And then in my MainViewController.m the method:

```
-(void) someMethod{
    searchBar.text = @"TEST";
    NSLog(@"TEST");
}
```

When I call the app that is in the background using a url scheme the application handleOpenURL method is executed and the "someMethod" is executed too, I can see in the console log "TEST" but the text value in my searchbar  doesn't change, the searchbar is working well because in my app I can set the text value from other methods, but only when the method is called from the appDelgate the interface seems "disconnected""

Any ideas? I can imagine that I;m missing something very simple.

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a view controller but not putting it on the screen. You either need to find your existing instance of the main view controller, or push the one you have just made onto the screen, by setting it as the windows root view controller or similar (can't say without more details, I'm afraid).

Answer (score 0):

When you do the following:

```
MainViewController *mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
[mainVC someMethod];
```

The view of `mainVC` is not loaded yet, and the IBOutlet `searchBar` is still `nil`.